# Ionic - File Plugin not working on device

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm trying to convert a base64 Image into a ".png" file. I am using the Ionic native file plugin to do this. First I am converting the base64 image into a Blob and then converting this Blob into a ".png" file.

When testing this in the web browser via "ionic serve" everything works perfectly but when testing this on an emulator or on a physical device it doesn't seem to work. The code runs without errors but when trying to log out the file type or file size I am getting 0 for the size and undefined for the type.

```
  let base64 = this.formData.getParentSignature();

  let signatureBlob = this.getBlob(base64);

  let signatureFileName = firstName+"-"+lastName+"-Parent-"+"Signature.png";

  var blob = new Blob([this.parentSignature], {type: 'image/png'});
  var filePhoto = new File([signatureBlob], signatureFileName);
```

Comment: Hope you are using this.file.writeFile(fileDirectory, filename, blobdata) method.

Comment: I'm uploading this image to a server, via multipart/form-data. The image uploads when running the app via the web browser but fails on a real device. I've narrowed the problem down to the file not being created on a physical device.

The server only accepts image files unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out myself and I'm posting it here in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

```
  let base64 = this.formData.getParentSignature();

  let signatureBlob = this.getBlob(base64);

  let signatureFileName = firstName+"-"+lastName+"-Parent-"+"Signature.png";

  var blob = new Blob([signatureBlob], {type: 'image/png'});
  var filePhoto = new File([signatureBlob], signatureFileName);
```

Then I was able to rename the file:

```
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');

  let form = new FormData();
  form.append('files', blob, signatureFileName);
```